# Temperamental `nestRemoting()` sometimes can't find relation

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop, loopback

I'm implementing the (not so well documented) loopback method `nestRemoting()` as follows:

```
module.exports = function(MyModel) {
    MyModel.on('attached', function() {
        MyModel.nestRemoting('relationName');
    });
}
```

However this seems to be very temperamental. Sometimes it works, but most of the time I get:

```
Relation `relationName` does not exist for model `MyModel`
    at ....stacktrace....
    .....
```

Does anyone know why this error might be occurring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I found the solution only moments after posting - you can only do `nestRemoting` after the model has been `attatched`... not `attached`. Simple spelling mistake can fix all woes.

Perhaps this post will help someone else trying to nest endpoints.